# css footer moving up when window shrinks

Tags: html, css

Hi i have a css style sheet which works fine untill you shrink the window then the footer gradualy moves up, i have been looking at it for a long time and i really carnt figure out what is wrong with my code here is my css stle sheet:

```
/*               *
*      Misc      *
*                */   
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
h1{
 font-size: 28px;
}
h2{
 font-size: 16px;
}
body{
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
}
/*               *
*      Header    *
*                */   
.header{
 background: grey;
 height: 90px;
 color: white;
}
.header h1{
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
 float: left;
}
.header .searchBox{
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
 float: right;
}
.header .nav{
 position: relative;
 top: 50px; 
}
.header .nav li{
 padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 5px;
 background:black;
}
.header .nav ul {
 text-align: center; 
}
.header .nav li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
.header .nav ul li a:hover{
 background: lightgrey;
}

/*               *
* Middle Content *
*                */

.middle{
 overflow:auto;
}   

/*               *
*  Navigatioin   *
*                */   
.navigation{
 position:absolute;
 background: #EEEEEE;
 width: 130px;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 height: 70%;
 border-right-style:solid;
 border-right-width:2px;
}
.navigation h2{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.navigation .nav{
 padding: 0px 10px 20px 0px;
 text-align: right; 
}
.navigation .nav li{
 list-style: none;
}
/*               *
*     Content    *
*                */   
.content { 
 background: #EEEEEE;
 margin-left : 13px;
 margin-right : 5px;
 margin-top : 5px;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 position:absolute;
 left: 130px;
 overflow:auto;

}
.content .item{
 background: #DDDDDD;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 margin: 5px;
}
.content .item p{
 margin: 5px;
}
.content .item h2{
 margin-left: -5px;
}
/*               *
*      Footer    *
*                */   
.footer{
 background: #EEEEEE;
 height: 50px;
 bottom: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%
}
.footer .nav ul li{
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 5px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: inline;
}
.footer .nav ul {
 text-align: center; 
}

.footer .copyright{
 text-align: center; 
}
```

and the html for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>XYZ</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Defult.css" />
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class ="header">
 <h1>XYZ</h1>
 <div class ="searchBox">
  <form action="">
  <p><label>Search:<input type="text" /></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
  </p>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class ="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class ="middle">
 <div class ="navigation">
  <h2>About</h2>
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Values</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Leadership</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Company History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Environmental Responsibility</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class ="content">
   <h1>About XYZ</h1>
  <div class ="item">
   <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut libero ac aenean luctus, lacus blandit, consectetuer cras litora massa. Massa condimentum, etiam nunc, quis egestas quis magna vitae velit porttitor, pulvinar at vivamus. Odio nec posuere maecenas tincidunt, quam est id felis
    adipiscing eros, condimentum ac lorem ante in. Molestie est risus nullam, sed dui dictum integer metus, praesent consequat nunc facilisis ante. Gravida tristique vivamus. Risus vel malesuada, dui malesuada lorem id, quam nibh at tellus id ullamcorper, ligula
    vitae dictumst nisl leo. Sit natoque viverra sollicitudin diamlorem, eu massa lacinia pretium laoreet metus, rutrum ut odio molestie porta penatibus.
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class ="item">
   <h2>Sit Consequat Molestie</h2>
   <p>Sit consequat molestie elit tempus et justo, conubia magna est, rutrum eleifend duis commodo ante mattis, posuere metus vel curabitur vitae leo purus. Vivamus gravida ante reprehenderit, consequat cursus id placerat, mauris ultrices, urna ultrices, ut suspendisse
    accumsan imperdiet sit. Pede tristique rerum auctor suspendisse. Amet rutrum enim nullam tempor, a wisi, morbi vel volutpat sollicitudin platea, lectus velit nec. Dui sed, malesuada ac in, natoque vitae ornare interdum nulla et felis. Vitae praesent pede duis
    varius lectus, suspendisse tincidunt, eleifend eget quis dolor donec ut. Felis porta ultricies, aliquam et luctus scelerisque parturient, massa ultricies et tempus eu ullamcorper mus. Donec maecenas nullam in, rutrum a, odio nibh ut tortor nunc sollicitudin
    sem, scelerisque ac pede mollis massa vel ullamcorper, scelerisque velit nulla vestibulum.
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class ="item">
   <h2>Sapien Quisque Dictum</h2>
   <p>Sapien quisque dictum arcu integer, elementum magna pharetra ipsum eu, nunc nulla id error odio nulla nec, pede non nec dolor mauris, eget id morbi. Nibh nibh imperdiet a imperdiet dapibus, sed auctor sed arcu morbi imperdiet in, morbi et ipsum mollis sem
    massa ut. Ac sit nibh curabitur aliquet, arcu dictum varius justo. Ut in. Donec varius ad blandit, id praesent condimentum mauris magna adipiscing vitae, at dui libero nam sed ac nibh. Turpis et vel sem tempus, pellentesque id mi vitae eu eros, nonummy sagittis
    eu, laoreet dolor praesent volutpat lorem, volutpat lorem sodales consequat in adipiscing convallis. Dolor ipsum integer vivamus adipiscing a tincidunt, nibh leo, vitae ac velit vestibulum porta porttitor amet, lacinia ut tortor aliquam.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class ="footer">
 <div class ="nav">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Site Index</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Legal Notice</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Privacy Statement</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class ="copyright">
  <p>&copy; 2010 XYZ Trading Ltd.</p>
 </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is pretty easy to accomplish without scripting.  The one concession you have to make is having the footer's height be a percentage.

1. Wrap content, height 90%, overflow scroll
2. Footer, height 10%

Like so (didn't proof it in IE):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>XYZ</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Defult.css" />
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 <style>
  #wrap { height:90%; position:relative; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; }
  .footer { height:10%; margin:0; padding:0; min-height:35px;} 
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div class ="header">
 <h1>XYZ</h1>
 <div class ="searchBox">
  <form action="">
  <p><label>Search:<input type="text" /></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
  </p>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class ="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class ="middle">
 <div class ="navigation">
  <h2>About</h2>
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Values</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Leadership</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Company History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Environmental Responsibility</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class ="content">
   <h1>About XYZ</h1>
  <div class ="item">
   <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut libero ac aenean luctus, lacus blandit, consectetuer cras litora massa. Massa condimentum, etiam nunc, quis egestas quis magna vitae velit porttitor, pulvinar at vivamus. Odio nec posuere maecenas tincidunt, quam est id felis
    adipiscing eros, condimentum ac lorem ante in. Molestie est risus nullam, sed dui dictum integer metus, praesent consequat nunc facilisis ante. Gravida tristique vivamus. Risus vel malesuada, dui malesuada lorem id, quam nibh at tellus id ullamcorper, ligula
    vitae dictumst nisl leo. Sit natoque viverra sollicitudin diamlorem, eu massa lacinia pretium laoreet metus, rutrum ut odio molestie porta penatibus.
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class ="item">
   <h2>Sit Consequat Molestie</h2>
   <p>Sit consequat molestie elit tempus et justo, conubia magna est, rutrum eleifend duis commodo ante mattis, posuere metus vel curabitur vitae leo purus. Vivamus gravida ante reprehenderit, consequat cursus id placerat, mauris ultrices, urna ultrices, ut suspendisse
    accumsan imperdiet sit. Pede tristique rerum auctor suspendisse. Amet rutrum enim nullam tempor, a wisi, morbi vel volutpat sollicitudin platea, lectus velit nec. Dui sed, malesuada ac in, natoque vitae ornare interdum nulla et felis. Vitae praesent pede duis
    varius lectus, suspendisse tincidunt, eleifend eget quis dolor donec ut. Felis porta ultricies, aliquam et luctus scelerisque parturient, massa ultricies et tempus eu ullamcorper mus. Donec maecenas nullam in, rutrum a, odio nibh ut tortor nunc sollicitudin
    sem, scelerisque ac pede mollis massa vel ullamcorper, scelerisque velit nulla vestibulum.
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class ="item">
   <h2>Sapien Quisque Dictum</h2>
   <p>Sapien quisque dictum arcu integer, elementum magna pharetra ipsum eu, nunc nulla id error odio nulla nec, pede non nec dolor mauris, eget id morbi. Nibh nibh imperdiet a imperdiet dapibus, sed auctor sed arcu morbi imperdiet in, morbi et ipsum mollis sem
    massa ut. Ac sit nibh curabitur aliquet, arcu dictum varius justo. Ut in. Donec varius ad blandit, id praesent condimentum mauris magna adipiscing vitae, at dui libero nam sed ac nibh. Turpis et vel sem tempus, pellentesque id mi vitae eu eros, nonummy sagittis
    eu, laoreet dolor praesent volutpat lorem, volutpat lorem sodales consequat in adipiscing convallis. Dolor ipsum integer vivamus adipiscing a tincidunt, nibh leo, vitae ac velit vestibulum porta porttitor amet, lacinia ut tortor aliquam.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div><!--/wrap -->
<div class ="footer">
 <div class ="nav">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Site Index</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Legal Notice</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Privacy Statement</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class ="copyright">
  <p>&copy; 2010 XYZ Trading Ltd.</p>
 </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position: fixed` for the footer.

Comment: Nope just made the div its min size and even then it still stayed where it was and the text overflowed underneath it

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes:

```
.footer{
 background: #EEEEEE;
 height: 50px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top:20px;
}

.content { 
 background: #EEEEEE;
 margin-left : 13px;
 margin-right : 5px;
 margin-top : 5px;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 position:relative;
 overflow:auto;
}

.navigation{
 position:relative;
 background: #EEEEEE;
 width: 130px;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 height: 70%;
 border-right-style:solid;
 border-right-width:2px;
}
```

You were overusing the `absolute` position setting. In essence, you implemented a "sticky footer."

Comment: ahh thats allmost perfect! apart from i want the footer to stick to the bottom of the page

Comment: Isn't that what you originally had? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: no the footer was stook to the bottom and when i resized the page to smaller then what was in the content the footer would move up and the content would overflow underneath the footer which isnt what i wanted it to do i just wanted the content to go in to a scrolled area

Comment: @user51: So you essentially want the footer to stick to the bottom of the window, or the bottom of the content if the window is lower than the height of the content? I'm afraid such behaviour is only achievable through scripting.

Answer (score 0):

With position:absolute and bottom:0 your div will always be at the bottom of it's container(body).  When you resize the screen it will move like you said.  It seems like you use position:absolute a lot in your css, which makes it so those objects can't have other items position based on their position.

In order to get your footer to align properly at the bottom of your content,  you will have to switch your main containers(header, middle, content) to be position:relative and float:left.

If you want your footer to always be on the bottom of the page, even when the content doesn't reach the bottom, that's much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

try to set `min-height` to the content area which is above the footer